# I'm sending email via command line using linux accounts but it is adding @mail.hostname.com

Tags: linux, email

```
mail -s "subject" $user
```

I'm sending email via command line using linux accounts but it is adding @mail.hostname.com

so the username becomes user@mail.hostname.com

Is there are way that it just email using local accounts without @mail.hostname.com or change it automatically using @hostname.com

---

```
cd /home/dir/11   
du -m --max-depth=1 | sed 's/[./]//g' | while read space user 
do
    if [ $space -gt 100 ]
                   then

        mail -s "using over 100MB " $user <<MAIL
$user:
You are now using $space MB in your home directory.
The total amount of diskspace allowed is 100 MB.

MAIL
  fi

done
```

---

It is adding the hostname of the machine while sending mail user@mail.hostname.com where it should be user@hostname.com , i cant change the local machine hostname since there are some other connections using it. The mail is bouncing back since address is wrong:

> This is the Postfix program at host mail.hostname.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>                The Postfix program
> ```
>
> (expanded from ): unknown user:
>   "user1"

Comment: What do you mean by "*it is adding @mail.hostname.com*"?

Comment: it is adding the hostname of the machine. $user is the user list. How do I remove the hostname or change it to hostname.com without modifying the hostname of the machine

Comment: Did you check `/etc/mailname`?

Comment: **Where** is this hostname being added?  Please **show** us, rather than **telling** us.

Comment: I edited my post added the script im working on sorry bout that

Comment: Why not simply edit your script to contain the full address instead of just the username?

Comment: Honestly, I think JennyD's idea is simple, elegant, and The Right Thing.  It would be the work of about 20 keystrokes to add the hostname to the user emailed, thus solving the problem if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this document :
http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic

Here's excerpt from link.

First you need add generic map table to main.cf.

```
  /etc/postfix/main.cf:
      smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Then put your mappings ( how outgoing mail will be rewritten ) into "/etc/postfix/generic" .
Left hand side is adress to rewrite, the other is the address you need ...

```
  /etc/postfix/generic:
      his@localdomain.local               hisaccount@hisisp.example
      her@localdomain.local               heraccount@herisp.example
      @localdomain.local                  hisaccount+local@hisisp.example
```

It's also possible to use regexps..

```
  /etc/postfix/main.cf:
      smtp_generic_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/generic_re
```

In /etc/postfix/generic_re :

```
  /^(.*)@mail.hostname.com$/   ${1}@hostname.com
```

after that you should reload postfix

```
 postfix reload
```